# Dataflow Pipeline workers stall when passing extra arguments in PipelineOptions

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow job defined in Apache Beam that works fine normally but breaks when I attempt to include all of my custom command line options in the `PipelineOptions` that I pass to `beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)`. It fails after the graph is constructed, but before the first step starts, because the worker becomes unresponsive after starting up and eventually the job times out with no useful logs.

I would like to pass my custom options because only the options that you pass directly to the pipeline show up on the right hand side in the Dataflow console UI, and its very handy to be able to see them.

Full [broken example is here](https://github.com/whylabs/dataflow-templates/blob/timeout-repro/src/ai/whylabs/templates/profile_query_template.py). The old version that works looked more or less like this

```py
def run():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Many parser.add_argument lines

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        # Pipeline definition
```

The code that doesn't work looks like this

```py
class CustomOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        # same lines of parser.add_argument

def run():
    pipeline_options = CustomOptions()
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        # Same pipeline definition
```

Here are the extra keys that I end up passing into the `PipelineOptions` object.

```bash
api_key
dataset_id
date_column
date_grouping_frequency
input_bigquery_sql
input_mode
org_id
output
output_executable_path # This one isn't really me, it just ends up in there
```

Setting aside that the argparse/PipelineOptions API seems to be based entirely off of side effects, I can't make sense of why this might lead to the job failing to start. My best guess is that one of the options I'm passing through are overwriting/having some unintended side effect on the worker, but I've done this sort of thing before so I know its possible in general to pass options through like this and have the pipeline work.

Can someone spot some issue that might cause the first worker to become unresponsive? Something about the way I'm passing options in seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tested with your arguments and Beam version `2.41.0` and Python `3.8.12` :

```
"api_key": "test",
"dataset_id": "test",
"date_column": "test",
"date_grouping_frequency": "test",
"input_bigquery_sql": "test",
"input_mode": "test",
"org_id": "test",
"output": "test",
"output_executable_path": "test"
```

In the `Beam` options :

```py
class CustomOptions(PipelineOptions):

    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument("--api_key", help="Api key", required=True)
        parser.add_argument("--dataset_id", help="dataset ID", required=True)

        parser.add_argument("--date_column", help="datdate_column", required=True)
        parser.add_argument("--date_grouping_frequency", help="date_grouping_frequency", required=True)
        parser.add_argument("--input_bigquery_sql", help="input_bigquery_sql", required=True)
        parser.add_argument("--input_mode", help="input_mode", required=True)
        parser.add_argument("--org_id", help="org_id", required=True)
        parser.add_argument("--output", help="output", required=True)
        parser.add_argument("--output_executable_path", help="output_executable_path", required=True)
```

In the `Beam` pipeline :

```py
def run():
    custom_pipeline_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(CustomOptions)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
       # Get your custom option arguments
       custom_pipeline_options.api_key
       custom_pipeline_options.dataset_id
       ......
```

When the argument `output_executable_path` is a part of options, I have the following error :

```
[2022-11-18, 22:51:38 UTC] 
{beam.py:127} WARNING - argparse.ArgumentError: argument --output_executable_path: conflicting option string: --output_executable_path
```

There is a conflict with an argument used internally on `Beam`.

When I remove the argument `output_executable_path` from options, the `Dataflow` works without issue.

Can you test without this argument please ?

Comment: I just pushed a repro git repo with the exact code, I don't think your repro is exactly what I did, sorry. Its here now: https://github.com/whylabs/dataflow-templates/blob/timeout-repro/src/ai/whylabs/templates/profile_query_template.py. You should be able to run that too, I updated the README for this issue.

Comment: I guess there's a chance that the way that I'm running this is part of the problem as well? https://github.com/whylabs/dataflow-templates/blob/timeout-repro/Makefile#L23-L39

Comment: I don't explicitly pass in `--output-executable-path`, it just ends up there magically because of something that the beam sdk is doing under the hood. I don't care about it at all and I don't set it  when I run the pipeline.

Comment: Simplified makefile/readme a bit to remove the custom container stuff and just use a requirements.txt file. Doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Ok I am going to test it as soon as possible, and keep you informed.